# How do you get Black Dye besides buying it?

Tags: guild-wars-2

With a selling price pushing 3G, Black Dye is clearly in demand. Other than buying it, how can someone get it? Random drops only? Can it be forged with Mystic Coins?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- All monsters can drop [Unidentified Dye](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Unidentified_Dye).
- You can very rarely get Unidentified Dye from gathering wild plants (with the sickle).
- There are sparse reports that a [rare Unidentified Gray Dye](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Unidentified_Gray_Dye_(Rare)), made by chefs, may produce Black dye when opened.
- You can combine 4 dyes in the Mystic Forge for a chance of another random dye.

Comment: You can also put dyes in the mystic forge, which presumably would give you a chance of receiving a Black Dye.

Comment: Just to clarify, if i specifically want only Black Dye is there a way to make that happen? I was initially thinking a recipe at the Mystic Forge but it sounds like that is still a chance for Black to show up and not a certainty.

Comment: @TapanZee No, it's all random. You cannot specifically make and receive Black Dye. You have to buy it from other players.

Comment: As an update to this question, the April 2014 feature pack changed how dyes are acquired. All unlocked colors are now account-bound, but unidentified dyes no longer drop from monsters or gathering. They can still be acquired from certain story rewards and black lion chests.